# Bounty question, one triple upvoted answer, no comment in 6 days

Tags: discussion, bounty

**Scenario:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51110256/5198140) just had a bounty. The bounty, and now the grace period has expired. Mine is the sole answer and has 3 upvotes. The answer was posted 6 days ago. The OP has not commented on the answer (or the question) since that day, but has been active elsewhere on the site, asking another question since then. I've just been auto-awarded half the bounty.

**Question:** Clearly, it's their bounty to waste, but would it have been rude of me to nudge the OP for some feedback? Should I have http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive, which I've seen done? Other suggestions on how I could have assisted the OP to reach a solution within the allotted time?

Comment: Nudging would not have made any difference, the OP has not visited the site in the past 4 days.  This is typical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Clearly, it's their bounty to waste, but would it have been rude of me
>   to nudge the OP for some feedback?

It would have been noise, to be honest. Yes, it's unfortunate that OP wasted half of their bounty, but at least you got half. After all, you're in it to make valueable Q/A content that helps people other then the OP also. In that vein, your answer wasn't to waste.

> Should I have http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive, which I've
>   seen done?

Your votes (up and down) are of course yours to do with as you please (so long as you don't serially target another user), but I wouldn't. You're supposed to vote on the content as a signal for future users to judge it, not because OP slighted you in some way. You didn't think the question was worth downvoting when you first saw it, and you clearly found it interesting enough to provide a helpful (as judged by the community) answer, so why downvote it now? Try to divorce the content from the user who wrote it.

> Other suggestions on how I could have assisted the OP to reach a
>   solution within the allotted time?

This is the name of the game here on Stack Overflow, and a huge part of why the primary goal isn't to help OP, but to build a quality collection of questions and answers: OP can leave at any moment. They may or may not have seen and used your answer. But future readers might, and that's the goal. You can't do anything if an OP decides they don't care anymore or if they forget, so don't fret about it.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't down-vote a post because the poster "didn't respond". **Vote on post content, not on poster behavior**. And I wouldn't comment on votes in general. It rarely helps.

Also, you answered a question you admitted wasn't top-notch (e.g. lacking an MCVE), and your answer has plenty of guesses and debugging suggestions. Maybe, in the future, you should try to help improve the question *before* answering, not *after* doing it. That's what comments are for.

The bounty poster paid for the attention and got it, and you profited from that attention as well. They are not obligated to actually award the bounty, and getting frustrated about it doesn't help anyone.

You've answered an unclear question with a bunch of guesses and tips, and still got up-votes and part of the bounty. I would say that's not a bad result for you.

But if you want to have a better experience in SO, save your answers for better quality questions, and/or help the poster to clarify their question before actually producing an answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem with being unresponsive is that someone has left a comment asking for clarification, i.e., the content is lacking important details that need to be added to the question in order to make it answerable. The question isn't answerable because its content is lacking, which is worthy of a downvote. The solution is to keep track of your question, and when people ask for clarification, give it. Dropping your question and then getting on a flight to China isn't a good plan.